# New answer repeats old answer

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c) from 3 years, ago, a new answer has just been posted by "Duke". However that answer is just repeating the existing answer by "xanatos" , with a little bit of extra text copy-pasted from the link provided by xanatos.

What should happen in this situation?

Comment: That doesn't look like a copy-pasted answer. I wouldn't do anything with it from what I can see. The code is different, so is the explanation, nothing seems to be plagarized.

Comment: The entire new answer apart from the first paragraph, is copy-pasted from the link provided by the old answer

Comment: Ok, so he did a better link-answer than xantos did. Even if you allow that he knew about the link *because* of xantos's answer, its still not breaking any rules, or even acting unethically.

Comment: OK. I was worried about the "clutter" angle rather than the plagiarism one, since this answer does not add anything new that is not already present in other answers

Comment: Personally, I don't see it as clutter. We'll see if anyone else has an opinion though!

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't really look like a repeated answer.

Granted, they both link to the same page. Both pull different quotes and code however, and even seem to focus on different aspects. Given the use of official documentation, I would even suspect they independently knew about it if the answer wasn't so late.

Even allowing for the second user discovering the first user's link and using it to make a new answer, nothing seems to have been plagiarized.

I don't see the need for any action in this case. In general, you would flag the post as being plagiarized (include a link to the original) if you suspect someone of unethical behavior.